# scp error: yntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm using scp to copy a file to my local machine. The file is an html file and I think the error is due to the html markup, as the error is :

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
 /home/admin/web/domain.tld/document_errors/50x.html-old: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'
```

How can I avoid such an error?

Comment: Please update your question with the exact command you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a Windows end-of-line problem. `dos2unix` will fix your problem. From `man dos2unix`:

```
   In DOS/Windows text files a line break, also known as newline, is a combination of two characters: a Carriage Return (CR) followed by a Line Feed (LF). In Unix text
   files a line break is a single character: the Line Feed (LF). In Mac text files, prior to Mac OS X, a line break was single Carriage Return (CR) character. Nowadays
   Mac OS uses Unix style (LF) line breaks.
```